# What is the name for material being transported via machinery?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

If you transport material by truck/plane/boat, it is "[cargo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cargo)".

Is there a word that describes material that is being transported by machinery in an industrial setting, like in a pipeline / on a conveyor belt / in a bin or bucket? ("load"? "material"?)

Comment: I can't think of a generic term for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skimmed an [article](https://www.thomasnet.com/articles/materials-handling/understanding-conveyor-systems/#:%7E:text=Common%20conveyor%20belting%20materials%20include,depending%20on%20the%20throughput%20required.), "Understanding Conveyor Systems."  It uses the following terms:

**material(s)**

**product(s)**

Comment: But far too ballpark for a decent answer on a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - this is technical language and I imagine OP would get better results from a group of engineers.

Answer (score 0):

"[**Pipeline transport**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_transport)" can be used but specifically only for transporting a liquid/gas via pipes.

Being more generic, I would suggest "load" or "goods".